# how to host ejs (Embedded JavaScript templating) , expressjs app in vercel

Tags: vercel

i want to host my expressjs application at vercel but not wo0rking at vercel my view is available at
This application is built  in expressjs and nodejs

```
views/index.ejs
```

i have also already added vercel.json file in my project

please answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on Vercel, according to the following discussion:

https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4541